# Filter more than One ID to add attributes

Tags: jquery, filter

I am using this code to add a "top" attribute's value to all the ids with the transcript word.

Here is how the DIV look :-

```
 <div id="transcript36a_page2" class="pop-out" style="display: block; position: fixed; opacity: 1; z-index: 11400; left: 50%; margin-left: -425px; top: 157px; margin-top: 0px;">
   <a class="modal_close" href="#"><img src="images/empty.png" alt=""></a>
   <img src="./images/6a.png" border="0" alt="">
```

The JQuery Code I use is:-

```
 $(this).leanModal(
        {
            top: $(this).filter('[id*="transcript"]')[0] ? 500 : null,
            closeButton: ".modal_close, .modal_close_for_shoutout"
        }
    );
```

This adds the "top" value for any div with **transcript** in it. Problem is that now I want it to filter all the divs with **shoutout** too. Is there any efficient way that I can filter more then one DIV IDs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).leanModal({
     top: $(this).filter(function() {
              return this.id.indexOf('transcript') != -1 || 
                     this.id.indexOf('shoutout') != -1
          }).length ? 500 : null,
     closeButton: ".modal_close, .modal_close_for_shoutout"
});
```